# Not clear suggested edit reviewers correctly read rejected edit suggestion

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

In this [rejected edit suggestion](https://superuser.com/review/suggested-edits/1127854), I attempted make the paragraph description match the command solution, but the edit was rejected as being intended to reply to the author.

Can someone take please a look at this and tell me if this seems correct?

Comment: As per the answer it was incorrectly rejected and has now been approved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your edit is correct and should have been approved. In the [answer's revision history](https://superuser.com/posts/1165255/revisions#tab-6d840a4e-7b8a-4662-8b59-70fd137d7aa3-InlineHtml),  the answerer, in their 2018-11-21 edit meant to edit their answer to say `sudo tee` instead of `sudo dd`. The answerer replaced two instances, but it seems they just forgot to edit that instance you suggested.

Comment: As per the answer it was incorrectly rejected and has now been approved.